# NodeJS express receiving data from req stream

Tags: node.js, express

I'm receiving SOAP data that is being cut off before the footer (resulting in malformed XML).  I have contacted the sender and they are insisting it is our fault.  I've been logging what we've been receiving as follows.  Please tell me if there is any way that node will truncate the request stream.  (For example, how can I set the maxReceiveBuffer?)

```
req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
var fileString = '';
req.on('data', function (data, encoding, done) {
  fileString += data;
});
req.on('error', function(err) {
  // not happening
});
req.on('end', function() {
  // fileString can contain truncated XML.  The XML is around 100kb where it is being cut off.
});
```

I'm using express and please don't suggest I use a streaming xml validator.  Normally the files are less than 100kb.

Comment: To clarify: you're missing bytes at the end, right?  And both the file and `fileString` are truncated?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I think I will eventually create a very comprehensive test case for this scenario, but if anyone knows more than me off hand about what could cause a req stream to possibly "end" early that would be good info.

Comment: Are you able to check using something like tcpdump to see if you do actually receive all the data?

Comment: That would be a pretty major bug in streams, and seems pretty unlikely.  I would suspect something upstream - a load balancer killing the connection, or something like that.